# What to do about "match is not allowed in a const fn" error?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

When running the command:

```
cargo install cargo-generate --features vendored-openssl
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error[E0658]: `match` is not allowed in a `const fn`
   --> /home/pam/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/socket2-0.4.0/src/lib.rs:156:9
    |
156 | /         match address {
157 | |             SocketAddr::V4(_) => Domain::IPV4,
158 | |             SocketAddr::V6(_) => Domain::IPV6,
159 | |         }
    | |_________^
    |
    = note: for more information, see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49146

error[E0599]: no associated item named `MAX` found for type `usize` in the current scope
   --> /home/pam/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/socket2-0.4.0/src/sys/unix.rs:680:46
    |
680 |     msg.msg_iovlen = min(bufs.len(), IovLen::MAX as usize) as IovLen;
    |                                              ^^^ associated item not found in `usize`

error[E0599]: no associated item named `MAX` found for type `usize` in the current scope
   --> /home/pam/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/socket2-0.4.0/src/sys/unix.rs:740:46
    |
740 |     msg.msg_iovlen = min(bufs.len(), IovLen::MAX as usize) as IovLen;
    |                                              ^^^ associated item not found in `usize`

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0599, E0658.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
error: could not compile `socket2`.
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `cargo-generate v0.6.1`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-install7B7MDG`

Caused by:
  build failed
```

Using Rust version 1.41.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updating Rust worked for me:

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
```

New version 1.52.0

Comment: Seems to be this issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49146

Comment: Yeah. I was using an older version of `rust`.

Comment: I also executed `rustup update` to fix it.